# How do i choose names of students who took a test between 2 dates?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to show student id's who took a test both between 01/09/2007 - 31/12/2007 and between 01/01/2008 - 20/06/2008.
For some reason, it doesn't work. can I get some help from you? thank you
(The text below is what I wrote).

```
SELECT studentId
FROM gradesTbl
WHERE testDate BETWEEN "01/09/2007" AND "31/12/2007" AND
WHERE testDate BETWEEN "01/01/2008" AND "20/06/2008";
```

Comment: Remove the second `WHERE` keyword.

Comment: "between end-of-2007" AND "between start-of-2008" ... 

Comment: As these two criteria are actually running consecutively, you can just use `BETWEEN #01/09/2007# AND #20/06/2008#`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT g1.studentId
FROM gradesTbl AS g1
WHERE 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gradesTbl AS g2 WHERE g2.studentId = g1.studentId AND  g2.testDate BETWEEN "01/09/2007" AND "31/12/2007")
  AND 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gradesTbl AS g2 WHERE g2.studentId = g1.studentId AND  g2.testDate BETWEEN "01/01/2008" AND "20/06/2008");
```

But it would be better to select from the table `students`, which I believe you have and `studentId` in `gradesTbl` references its `id`:

```
SELECT s.studentId
FROM students AS s
WHERE 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gradesTbl AS g WHERE g.studentId = s.studentId AND  g.testDate BETWEEN "01/09/2007" AND "31/12/2007")
  AND 
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM gradesTbl AS g WHERE g.studentId = s.studentId AND  g.testDate BETWEEN "01/01/2008" AND "20/06/2008");
```

**Note:**
Dates in Access are not *Text* but *DateTime*:

```
BETWEEN #2007/09/01# AND #2007/12/31#
BETWEEN #2008/01/01# AND #2008/06/20#
```

Comment: Well done for interpreting the question correctly! I've submitted a minor edit to hopefully clear up the confusion it's generating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT studentId
FROM gradesTbl
GROUP BY studentId
HAVING SUM(IIF(testDate BETWEEN "01/09/2007" AND "31/12/2007", 1, 0) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(testDate BETWEEN "01/01/2008" AND "20/06/2008", 1, 0) > 0;
```

Each clause in the aggregation is counting the number of tests that each students takes in the specified period.  The `> 0` is returning only students who have taken at least one test.

Answer (score 0):

In Access the date separator is the `#` sign.
Also the logic operator here should be `OR`.
So the right query is

```
SELECT studentId 
FROM gradesTbl
WHERE testDate BETWEEN #01/09/2007# AND #31/12/2007# 
OR testDate BETWEEN #01/01/2008# AND #20/06/2008#;
```

Since a grade can NEVER answer to both conditions, if you want students who had tests in both period, you will need to group your data.

```
SELECT studentId, 
       sum(iif(testDate BETWEEN #01/09/2007# AND #31/12/2007#;1;0)) period1
       sum(iif(testDate BETWEEN #01/01/2008# AND #20/06/2008#;1;0)) period2
FROM gradesTbl
GROUP BY studentId
HAVING sum(iif(testDate BETWEEN #01/09/2007# AND #31/12/2007#;1;0)) > 0
   AND sum(iif(testDate BETWEEN #01/01/2008# AND #20/06/2008#;1;0)) > 0
```

Note: not tested - you might have to replace some ";" by "," depending on your regional settings.

Comment: The question is: "I need to show student id's who took a test between 01/09/2007 - 31/12/2007 **and** from 01/01/2008 - 20/06/2008"

Comment: @forpas you're right, by bad. But I will leave my answer as is for the moment, in case the problem is badly formulated :-) I hope the OP will clarify

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish this using `inner joins` on subqueries, e.g.:

```
select distinct t.studentid
from 
    (
        gradestbl t inner join
        (select distinct t.studentid from gradestbl t where t.testdate between #2007-09-01# and #2007-12-31#) q1
        on t.studentid = q1.studentid
    ) 
    inner join
    (select distinct t.studentid from gradestbl t where t.testdate between #2008-01-01# and #2008-06-20#) q2
    on t.studentid = q2.studentid
```